# Rails: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I run Ubuntu using VirtualBox on Windows 7.

When I launch "localhost:3000" (after I ran `rails s`), I got the following error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I installed XAMPP on Ubuntu, so my MySQL installation seems to be here: `/opt/lampp/var/mysql`
 (`mysql.sock` is there)

How should I connect my rails application to this MySQL installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the `socket` param in your `database.yml` (it defaults to /tmp/mysql.sock I think)

```
development:
adapter: mysql
encoding: utf8
database: yourapp_development
username: youruser
password: yourpassword
socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```